# Angular2 - toggle parent and children style on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, onclick

I am a complete noob with Angular2, so I apologize in advance if the question is very basic. So I have a side bar with an accordion menu. I need the parent and the children to change their background color on click (so basically on expanding the section). I understand that I can set an output on click on each div parent like so:

```
(click)="toggleClass()"
```

What is not very clear to me is what do I put in the constructor, in toggleClass(). I believe I need to somehow work with ngClass here, but I am a bit lost. See plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7YbXvVTv7rH9NY6xzLNG?p=preview).

Thanks!

Comment: Well your plunker is just a HTML document, could you post your components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NgClass Directive :https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

```js
export class NameComponent {
    booleanVariable: boolean;
    
    constructor() {
    }
    
    toggleClass(){
      if(!this.booleanVariable) {
        this.booleanVariable = true;
      else {
        this.booleanVariable = false;
      }
    }
}
```

```css
.className {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" (click)="toggleClass()" class="btn btn-transparent" [ngClass]="{'className': booleanVariable}"data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project-details">Projects</button>
```